# How To Fetch Email Ids Of My Facebook Friends

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the **email ids** of all my **facebook** friends from my android app. As of now I am able to fetch only the name and some **facebook** id. Please help me with your suggestions.

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 2):

**You can´t get the emails of friends. You can only get the email of users who authorized your App - with the `email` permission.**

All friend permission have been removed with v2.0 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

...but afaik it was never possible to get emails of friends.